# Blender Array + Ray sensor?

Tags: scripting, game-engine

For a simulation, I'm trying to get objects to form an array when sensed by another object in the game engine.

The ray sensor tracks targets just the way I want, so I wanted to use this as the main sensor for the simulation.

When the ray sensor detects another object within a specific radius, I would like said object to form a constraint with the ray sensor object and follow it around. I know how this can be done, but the question is, can it be done with multiple objects following in a straight line behind the sensor object, when detected? Similar to an array offset?

If so, can this be done without scripting?

('Track-to' constraints simply won't do, the sensor ability would be perfect!)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "If so, can this be done without scripting?"
Probably not.

Comment: sounds like a snake game, This is typically not done via physics engine.

Comment: @sdfgeoff  okay, thanks. i guess it's a pretty stupid question. i'll figure it out.

Comment: @Monster OK, yeah that's kind of what I was going for. Cool, I'll figure it out.